# Adding Web Elements to my list takes a long time. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I want to save the elements of certain link text into a list but when I run this code, it takes a lot of time and seems to run pretty slow.

```
static IWebDriver driver = null;
public static IList<string> linkList = new List<string>();

static void Main()
{
    readLinks();
}

public static void readLinks()
{
    IList<IWebElement> elementList = driver. 
        FindElements(By.LinkText("Click Here")).ToList();

    foreach (IWebElement ele in elementList)
    {
        String eleHref = ele.GetAttribute("href");
        linkList.Add(eleHref);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a [mre]? You never set `driver`, it's always null.

Comment: And can you expand what you mean by "a long time"? Speed can depend on your code, but can also be affected by the computer hardware and the specific environment of your machine. What sort of timing are you looking at achieving?